# React Marquee module giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, marquee

I am getting an error in the Chrome Dev Tools Console when using the [react-text-marquee module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-marquee) in react.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue without changing the output to a string instead of JSX.

I should clarify that the functionality of the page is actually working correct, however it would be nice to get rid of errors in case they cause issues down the line.

**This is the chrome console error:**

```
09:43:29.747 index.js:2177 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `text` of type `array` supplied to `Marquee`, expected `string`.
    in Marquee (at Session.js:86)
    in Session (at Content.js:83)
    in div (at Content.js:88)
    in Content (at App.js:13)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:9)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2177
```

**The complete Session.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import Marquee from 'react-text-marquee';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

class Session extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            "showConceptLogo" : true,
            "logo" : "logo",
            "filmTitle": "2D Justice League",
            "classification": "PG",
            "sessionAttributes": [
                {
                    "key": "VMAX",
                    "text": "VMAX",
                    "color": "yellow",
                    "background": "red"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Gold",
                    "text": "Gold"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Vjnr",
                    "text": "Vjnr"
                },
                {
                    "key": "VPrem",
                    "text": "VPrem"
                },
                {
                    "key": "FWTC",
                    "text": "FWTC"
                },
                {
                    "key": "CC",
                    "text": "CC"
                }
            ],
            "screeningTime": "4:00PM"
        }
    }

    RenderAttributesElement(attr) {
        return (
            <span style={{color: attr.color, backgroundColor: attr.background}}>{attr.text} </span>
        );
    }

    ConceptLogo(props) {
        if (props.display) {
            return (
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    <h2>{props.logo}</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <this.ConceptLogo logo={this.state.logo} display={this.state.showConceptLogo} />
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <h2>{this.state.filmTitle}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    <h2>{this.state.classification}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-3">
                    <Marquee hoverToStop={true} loop={true} leading={3000} trailing={3000} text={this.state.sessionAttributes.map(this.RenderAttributesElement)} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1">
                    <h2>{this.state.screeningTime}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Session;
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob Removed as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of following options basically just hide the warning.

**Option 1**: change type of the `text` prop in runtime:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Marquee.propTypes.text = PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.string,
      PropTypes.array,
  ]);
```

However, this might pose a problem if the author of the library decides to make a change that will render your usage of their component incorrect.

**Option 2**: fork the repository, change `propTypes` field in source, and, after updating the version in package.json of the library, setup a link to it in your project's package.json:

```
"react-text-marquee": "git://github.com/yourusername/react-text-marquee"
```

After that you run `npm install` and now you have to maintain your copy of the library in case the author does bugfixes or something like that. You might even describe prop type better and make a pull request to the original repository.